# JNI how to access Java Object (Integer)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a JNI method to access java method which returns an Integer object. I do not want to return the primitive int type because this code will be modified to handle Generic objects. The following is what I have. I am not able to get the value of the Integer that I pass. The output at C++ side is something like

```
value = 0x4016f3d0
```

How can I get the actual value of Integer object that I pass at C++ end?

Please help.

Thanks,

-H

*GenericPeer.cpp*

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_GenericPeer_print (JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jobject data){
 jclass peerCls = jenv->GetObjectClass(data);
 jmethodID mGetValue = jenv->GetMethodID(peerCls, "getValue","()Ljava/lang/Integer;");
 if(mGetValue == NULL){
   return (-1);
 } 
 jobject value = jenv->CallObjectMethod(data, mGetValue);
 cout<<"value = "<<value<<endl;

}
```

*GenericPeer.java*

```
public class GenericPeer {
 public static native void print(Data d);
 static {
  System.load("/home/usr/workspace/GenericJni/src/libGenericJni.so");
 }
}
```

*Data.java*

```
public class Data {
 private Integer value;
 pubilc Data(Integer v){ 
  this.value = v;
 }
 public Integer getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(Integer value) {
 this.value = value;
 }
}
```

*Test.java (Main class)*

```
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args){
       Integer i = new Integer(1);
  Data d = new Data(i);
  GenericPeer.print(d);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to invoke the `intValue` method on the Integer instance to get its primitive value. Use `FindClass` instead of `GetObjectClass` (as in your code) to get a reference to the class java.lang.Integer and then `GetMethodID` and `CallObjectMethod` to actually invoke the `intValue` method.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks Jarnbjo,

It works now! This is what I have:

```
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_GenericPeer_print (JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jobject data){
      jclass peerCls = jenv->GetObjectClass(data);

     jmethodID mGetValue = jenv->GetMethodID(peerCls, "getValue","()Ljava/lang/Integer;");
     if (mGetValue == NULL){
       return(-1);
     }

     jobject value = jenv->CallObjectMethod(data, mGetValue);
     if(value == NULL){
      cout<<"jobject value = NULL"<<endl;
      return(-1);
     }

    //getValue()

     jclass cls = jenv->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
     if(cls == NULL){
       outFile<<"cannot find FindClass(java/lang/Integer)"<<endl;
     }
       jmethodID getVal = jenv->GetMethodID(cls, "intValue", "()I");
       if(getVal == NULL){
         outFile<<"Couldnot find Int getValue()"<<endl;
       }
       int i = jenv->CallIntMethod(value, getVal);
}
```

Comment: Why `Ljava/lang/Integer;`, and not `Ijava/lang/Integer;`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky because it is the standard JNI way to pass Java type "Lpackage_name/class_name;" L has nothing to do with Long or Int

Comment: @Flot2011 what's the difference

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There is actual code here and not like the copy paste explanation above.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `intValue()` method through jni interface.

1. First use `FindClass` to get `Integer` class reference.
2. To invoke `intValue` method, use `CallIntMethod` function. Here the method type signature is `()I`.

```
static int GetIntegerValue(JNIEnv *env, jobject value) {
    jclass integer_class = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
    return env->CallIntMethod(value, env->GetMethodID(integer_class, "intValue", "()I"));
}
```