# How to read an array of objects passed into JNI from Java

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

This might sound like a newbie question but I would like to know the proper way to read and iterative through an array of objects passed into JNI c++ from java.

For examples, the object has a signature of:

```
public class Node{
     public String name;
     public long uniqueId;
     public int rank;
}
```

And I pass an array of ten node objects into a native method:

```
nativeParse(nodes);
```

I would like to iterative through the objects and create new c++ objects from the data so that my c++ code can use them.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming is `newNodes[]` is your C++ array of objects, you can try something like this:

```
  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL nativeParse(JNIEnv *env, jint size, jobjectArray nodes)
  {
     for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
         newNodes[i]= (jobject) env->GetObjectArrayElement(nodes, i);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how do i access the fields inside the objects though?

Comment: take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630529/jni-how-to-access-java-object-integer

Comment: I'm glad to see that my answer was useful for this problem, although i'm not experienced in native method calls in Java.