# How to access Java static fields via the ndk

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I want to modify globals declared in java SDK via an NDK C function, eg:

```
public class NDKTest extends Activity
{
    static int myglobal = 0;

    static { System.loadLibrary("MyCLib"); }
    static public native void incrementmyglobal();
....
```

and in MyCLib:

```
#include "NDKTest.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NDKTest_incrementmyglobal

(JNIEnv * env, jobject jObj)
{
  /*
     this next line is obviously wrong, but illustrates how it would have
     been done had it been a purely C program
  */
  M.myglobal = M.myglobal + 1;
  return;
}
```

So my question is:

a/ What is the correct syntax of the offending line?

b/ How should the C header file look?

c/ How should the Android.mk file look?

I can compile and run various 'helloworld' NDK examples, but I find none that illustrate
how to modify a global declared in java. A supersimple example would be greatly appreciated!

I am programming using Linux command line (ant debug), and simple text editor (emacs).
Im not using Eclipse; have been programming C for years, and am a Java noob.
Destination platform is Android.
Cheers!

Comment: As far as I recall, int in Java != int in C. For the Android NDK they are called `jint` I believe.

Comment: this not a particular problem for Android, it's more about JNI in general, try to google something for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630529/jni-how-to-access-java-object-integer

Comment: incidentally, the line:
    M.myglobal = M.myglobal + 1;
should have read:
    NDKTest.myglobal = NDKTest.myglobal + 1;
didnt find how to edit my own question

Comment: To edit a question, click "edit" below the question tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is static, so its second parameter is a `jclass` pointer for the current class, not the current object pointer. Also note that the name of the native method must include the package name:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_mypackage_NDKTest_incrementmyglobal 
(JNIEnv * env, jobject jcl) 
{ 
  jfieldID fid = GetStaticFieldID(env, jcl, "myglobal", "I");
  int i = GetStaticIntField(env, jcl, fid);
  SetStaticIntField(env, jcl, fid, i+1);
  return; 
}
```

There's no need for a C header. The Android.mk should look like that of any helloworld example, with LOCAL_SRC_FILES changed to reflect yours.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is for optimisation purposes - i want a native c func to process a lot of info stored in globals. Do you think I should store the globals on the C side?

Comment: It looks like using 3 lines to manipulate a single memory location might be a bit slow. otherwise, its a top answer from Seva

Comment: Sorry, that's what JNI is like. You're not going to get a better answer. The best you can do - you can cache the FieldID somewhere. Just think very carefully as you design your C/Java boundary.

Comment: Seva, do you think i could write the whole app in C and just use the java side as a 'container'? ps. thanx for all the help!

Comment: The vast majority of Android API is Java only. You've already seen that calling Java from C is not pretty. If you're willing to live with that, go ahead. What do you need C for anyway?

Comment: I (think I) need C for maximum performance. this webpage convinced me of the benefits of the NDK:
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/96.html
and yes, calling Java from C is not pretty at all! But performance is essential, even if the truth isnt pretty. My app is maybe 20% finished - all in Java - and I already notice the low performance. I dont really use much of the Android API as im porting my app by hand from a C version i made a few years ago, in which I rolled pretty much everything myself. What do you suggest I should use?

Comment: Well, if it's for numeric performance, then maybe C is the way to go - but again, do profile on a real device to make sure. ARM CPU's aren't fast in general, and performance on the emulator is not indicative of anything. Anyway, unless your UI is OpenGL-based, I don't think all-C-no-Java is the right thing to do. Keep your physics in C, and your UI code in Java.

Comment: The UI is indeed OpenGL based, and I am profiling on a real device. I'd like to try some tests on declaring all globals within C (the 'Java as a container') approach. So, my next questions are:

A/ Are there any other methods to iterate over large amounts of global data in an efficient way?
B/ How do I access C globals from the Java SDK? (!)
and
C/ Have I just drifted long out of the scope the question I originally opened this forum for? (etiquette question)

Comment: Ask your next question(s) as questions. StackOverflow is not a discussion board.

Comment: I see. Sorry about that. Then I can declare this question answered. Thanks for your help.